# Get selected values from NgForm

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I have a component called dashboard.component.html that consists only of four select boxes that are within a form. I have a button that triggers a function called onSubmit() in dashboard.component.ts. I need the selected values from the form to be passed in to onSubmit() which then passes these values to a service. I can't seem to get the selected values--when I print them out to the console, I get [object Object].

dashboard.component.html:

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(escortForm)" #escortForm="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="driver" name="driver" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
    <option *ngFor="let driver of drivers" [value]="driver">{{driver.viewValue}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="pickup" name="pickup" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="escortService.selectedEscort.pickup">
    <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location">{{location.viewValue}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="dropoff" name="dropoff" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="escortService.selectedEscort.dropoff">
    <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location">{{location.viewValue}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="numPsngers" name="passenger" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="escortService.selectedEscort.passengers">
    <option *ngFor="let passenger of passengers" [value]="passenger">{{passenger.viewValue}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

dashboard.component.ts (only the relevant parts):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Chartist from 'chartist';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EscortService } from './shared/escort.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
declare var $:any;
declare var google: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    providers: [EscortService]
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private escortService : EscortService, private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

onSubmit(escortForm: NgForm){
       this.escortService.newEscort(escortForm.value);
    }
```

escort.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Escort } from './escort.model';

@Injectable()
export class EscortService {

  escortList : AngularFireList<any>;
  selectedEscort : Escort = new Escort();

  constructor(private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

  newEscort(escort : Escort){
        this.escortList.push({
            driver : escort.driver.toString(),
            pickup : escort.pickup,
            dropoff : escort.dropoff,
            passengers : escort.passengers,
            no_show : false,
            status : "",
            created : "",
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `select` item values appear to be objects, they should be set with `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="pickup" name="pickup" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="escortService.selectedEscort.pickup">
    <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [ngValue]="location">{{location.viewValue}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still not working. In the EscortService - newEscort() code above, when I print to console the escort that's being passed in, it says the first the first property (escort.driver) is [object Object] and I can't see the value from the select box.

Comment: Should you use `[(ngModel)]="escortService.selectedEscort.driver"` instead of `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"`? If it still doesn't work, please show the definition of the `Escort` class.

Comment: Make sure that you use `[ngValue]` for all 4 `option` lists. Also, please note that the selected value is the item object itself, not the text of the selected item.